# Append to HTML ignores content after space

Tags: javascript, html

I am appending input type using java script. but it is removing content after blank space

Java script code is

```js
var temp = '<input type="hidden" name="nearest[]" id="nearest" value='+distance+'_'+location+'>';
$('#nearest_div').append(temp);
```

```html
<div id="nearest_div"></div>
```

But if variable location is having space in name then it dont get append properly
for eg if  **location = United States**  then it appends **United** only and ignores content after space

Comment: `'<input type="hidden" name="nearest[]" id="nearest" value="'+distance+'_'+location+'">'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't quote `Value`, that's why it is not working.

For example if the value is "The United States of America", your code will produce a tag like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="nearest[]" id="nearest" value=The United States>`

but it should be:

`<input type="hidden" name="nearest[]" id="nearest" value="The United States">`

**I changed your code:**

```
  var temp = '<input type="hidden" name="nearest[]" id="nearest" value="'+distance+'_'+location+'>"';
  $('#nearest_div').append(temp);
```